# How do I pass a filter to Count?

Tags: count, django-views

Is it possible to put a filter into the Issue model whose items are getting counted here????

```
issues = Student.objects.annotate(Count('issue'))
```

I really need to filter it so as to get the desired outcome...
If not is there a way I can be able to get count of all Issues to a particular student?

```
class Issue(SafeDeleteModel):
    _safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE
    borrower_id = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book_id = models.ForeignKey(Books,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Student(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can filter what items are counted with the [**`filter=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate-filter). We can for example filter on the `book_id` with:

```
issues = Student.objects.annotate(
    num_issues=Count(
        'issue',
        filter=Q(issue__book_id_id=some_book_id)
    )
)
```

or to exclude soft deleted items, we can work with the `deleted` field that has been defined in your model (by the `django-safedelete` package):

```
issues = Student.objects.annotate(
    num_issues=Count(
        'issue',
        filter=Q(issue__deleted=False)
    )
)
```

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `_ids` to a `ManyToManyField` field, since Django
> it refers to a manager over the target objects. Therefore it should
> be `book`, instead of <s>`book_id`</s>.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, my Issue model has a _safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE, and I'd like to get only the undeleted items. It's returning all items, deleted and undeleted. since SOFT_DELETE is the default. How can I filter it to return only the undeleteds??? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @fakeMake: in that case, the model has defined a `deleted` field (by the `django-safedelete` package, so you can filter with that field.

Comment: Is this like deleted=True?

Comment: @fakeMake: the filter should work with `filter=Q(issue__deleted=False)`, since we are filtering the related `Issue`s.

Comment: I got Complex annotations require an alias

Comment: @fakeMake: yes if you start making `Count`s with a `filter`, you need to specify this with `.annotate(somename=...)`.

Comment: @fakeMake: for `some_name` you just fill in the name of the attribute that will store the annotation. In the template you can then access the number of issues with `some_student.some_name`.

Comment: See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

Comment: Be blessed for taking your time to sort me out.. Thanks.